# NodeJS múltiplos url em app.get Express

Tags: node.js, express.js

Tenho diversas urls (praticamente todas), que apontam para uma única página e uso o a seguinte linha para enviar o arquivo:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){ 
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/home.html');
});
```

Porém com isso,também arquivos que solicito ao meu site e etc, são redirecionados para a home, eu não gostaria de ter que criar uma nova linha para cada url solicitada, assim:

```
app.get('/urlA', function(req, res){ 
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/home.html');
});

app.get('/urlB', function(req, res){ 
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/home.html');
});
```

Seria possível fazer algo como o código abaixo?

```
app.get('/urlA, /urlB', function(req, res){ 
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/home.html');
});
```

Comment: Tente `app.get('/(urlA|urlB)', function(req, res) { ... }`

Comment: Recebo Invalid regular expression quando tento fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Express permite passar uma expressão regular como primeiro parâmetro:

```
app.get(/(urlA|urlB)/, (req, res) => { ... });
```

Ou:

```
app.get(/url(A|B)/, (req, res) => { ... });
```

Outra opção, um pouco mais abrangente:

```
app.get(/url[A-Z]/, (req, res) => { ... });
```

Mas também pode fazer algo assim:

```
function exemplo(req, res) => { ... }
app.get('urlA', exemplo);
app.get('urlB', exemplo);
```